# How to get webpack 4 to ignore image src

Tags: webpack

I'm using the CopyWebpackPlugin with Webpack 4 to copy an images folder to the dist folder in a production build, and I don't want Webpack to attempt to resolve or change `<img src="./images/flower.png">` anywhere in the application. And I mean anywhere in any mode.

For example, if I use html-loader to load an HTML snippet into a parent HTML file, I don't want Webpack to touch the img src values in that snippet because the snippet and its associated images may have been created by a designer who knows nothing about Webpack. Moreover, the application may have a dozen or a hundred such snippets. I don't know yet.

The rule in the config file currently looks like this:

```
test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/i,
use: [
  {
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: {
      name: '[path][name].[ext]?hash=[hash:20]',
      esModule: false,
      limit: 8192
    }
  }
]
```

I presume I need to add, change or remove a simple option in the Webpack config file, but I don't know which one.

I'm a newbie to Webpack, and I welcome any advice on how to accomplish this.

Many thanks, David.

Comment: It could be that html-loader is the issue. I still open for any and all advice.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and solved it by setting `html-loader`'s `attributes` flag to false.

> By default every loadable attribute (for example - < img
>   src="image.png">) is imported (const img = require('./image.png') or
>   import img from "./image.png""). You may need to specify loaders for
>   images in your configuration (recommended file-loader or url-loader).

https://webpack.js.org/loaders/html-loader/#attributes

Comment: Ben, many thanks. I'd given up on getting help. Have a good summer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this settings for webpack.config.js:

```js
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/i,
        loader: "html-loader",
        options: {
          // Disables attributes processing
          sources: false,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).